# What optimization method does LIBLINEAR use for training L1 regularized logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, regularization

LIBLINEAR:

- The page: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/
- The paper: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/liblinear.pdf
- The github: https://github.com/cjlin1/liblinear

I expect it to be coordinate descent, but I couldn't find the exact information from the above sources. Anybody knows? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is coordinate descent, here's the code for the solver for L1 regularized logistic regression:

https://github.com/cjlin1/liblinear/blob/6cd15778c0f271566a333c88cb86ba7c70ba14a1/linear.cpp#L1648

There's also a solver for the dual form of the problem, again using coordinate descent:

https://github.com/cjlin1/liblinear/blob/6cd15778c0f271566a333c88cb86ba7c70ba14a1/linear.cpp#L1206

Comment: One follow-up question, please. L1 regularized logistic regression is convex, and hence the optimum is deterministic with coordinate descent, right?

Comment: I think it is, "L1 regularized logistic regression requires solving a convex
optimization problem.", https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2006/AAAI06-064.pdf

Comment: I'm less certain of that, my understanding is that L1 logistic regression is convex. Thus my intuition is that if that two different random initializations both converge, it should be to the same parameters. Maybe you could end up two different answers if the algorithm didn't successfully converge?

Comment: If it's convex, why won't they converge? Do you mean a saddle point kind of situation?

Comment: in practical implementations you have stopping criteria...  ie when error delta is less than X

Answer (score 1):

The method used in the latest version of LIBLINEAR to solve the $\ell_1$ logistic problem is new GLMET method. It is a deterministic proximal Newton method. Each subproblem is solved by coordinate descent method.

Comment: Could you please add a url/paper to GLMET method?

Comment: I've edited your post to use math typesetting. If this edit does not match your intention, you can roll it back. More information about math typesetting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: please refer to https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/l1_glmnet/long-glmnet.pdf